# Python Selenium: Handling Webdriver exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautfilsoup for extracting app related information from Google Play Store. I am extracting app name, overall rating, no of people rated the app, and reviews posted by the reviewers. However, when I run the program it throws webdriver exception For instance: when program tries to retrieve information from this app ( 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tudasoft.android.BeMakeup&hl=en&showAllReviews=true'), it throws error. Here is my code:

```
import bs4 as bs
from selenium import webdriver 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(url)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

I got error on third line and the start of error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-270-4e8a1ef443f2> in <module>()
----> 1 soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

and end of error is:

```
(Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578706 (5f725d1b4f0a4acbf5259df887244095596231db),platform=Mac OS X 10.15.2 x86_64)
```

I tried to used exception handling but didn't fix the issue Could anyone guide me how to overcome this kind of situation?

Comment: If you see your Chrome driver `chromedriver=2.41.578706` and chrome versions `chrome=79.0.3945.88` are incompatible.First update your chrome driver and try it again.

Comment: I think the the issue is with the emojis in the reviews. At first I was getting the errors, But When I go into Dev Tools and remove those emojies, it runs fine. Not sure how to go about that issue though programatically. I read this [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7359)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
.
(Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578706 (5f725d1b4f0a4acbf5259df887244095596231db),platform=Mac OS X 10.15.2 x86_64)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to communicate with the **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=41.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.41*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v67-69**

- You are using *chrome=79.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v79.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 79**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.41* and the *Chrome Browser v79.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: For the last point you mentioned, if I am retrieving multiple url (using for loop), do I need to use driver.quit() at the end of loop (before loading the new url)?

Comment: @user2293224 It's always advisable to start each test in a cleaner way, i.e. spinning up a new _Browsing Context_ and in these cases you can easily `driver.quit()`. Having said that if your tests have dependency, you may have to make change to your _Test Architecture_ to reuse the existing session. In this case you can't `driver.quit()`. Inshort significance of `driver.quit()` is to keep the memory usage lower.

Comment: I followed your instructions: updated the chrome driver, selenium, and restarted the system. When I ran the program, it throws same error but with some different details. Here is the end of the error message:

Comment: (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88), this time it didn't print version of webdriver

Comment: @user2293224 Great, so we have solved the error you mentioned with in your question. Shouldn't we close this discussion and discuss the current error within a new thread?